# Фигурные границы для div

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день,

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли задать, например для блока div, фигурные границы, например по какой-то замысловатой формуле типа кривых Базье. Знаю, что в CSS есть набор простых фигур, Rectangle, triangle и т.д. Но не уверен как при этом JS видит границы такого блока.
Например, есть наш фигурный div (пусть будет в форме облачка), в котором перемещается и от стенок оталкивается другой div круглой формы.

Спасибо.

Comment: вроде никак кроме задания фонового изображения и расчета на javascript находится ли внутренний див внутри нужных координат и вычисления когда надо сменить вектор движения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPD***

Используйте svg Как для дива с облаками,так и для шара.Либо вообще flash)
По просьбам участников поясняю.
Возможности языка:
Описание путей (англ. path). Позволяет задать любую фигуру компактной строкой, описывающей путь от начальной точки до конечной через любые промежуточные координаты.

Строка с данными задаётся атрибутом d тега path и содержит команды, закодированные набором букв и чисел. Буква определяет тип команды, числа — её параметры (чаще всего — координаты). Команды позволяют описывать фигуры, состоящие из отрезков прямых (L, H, V), **кривых Безье** (C, S, Q, T) и дуг (A).  В версиях SVG до 1.2 включительно описание путей возможно только в пикселях.

С помощью ECMAScript или JavaScript можно описывать даже самые сложные сценарии, связанные с **математическими вычислениями координат и пропорций фигур**. Вместе с интерактивностью и SMIL анимацией это дает очень широкие возможности для разработчиков веб-графики.

[Источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG)

Comment: Вот уж flash точно лесом.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Тогда svg

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Пояснил.От себя еще добавлю.Почему нельзя создать допустим облака в svg или наоборот шар. На сайте в конечном итоге все будет блоками.Тот же шар к примеру не сможет понять границы облаков.

Answer (score 0):

Может это подойдет [CSS masking](http://htmlhook.ru/css-masking.html) http://htmlhook.ru/css-masking.html